# How to have multiple complex rotation apply to the background

Tags: reactjs, antd

Currently, I have the two linear-gradients I want to apply to the same background.

It should give me 2 triangles, and with 180deg rotation.

linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 99, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(70, 233, 255, 0.1) 100% ),

linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 99, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(70, 233, 255, 0.1) 100%),

I want to apply this to the same background.

I have tried the following, and both failed:

Failed 1:

```
background: "linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 99, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(70, 233, 255, 0.1) 100%, 270deg, rgba(0, 99, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(70, 233, 255, 0.1) 100%)"
```

Failed 2:

```
background: "linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 99, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(70, 233, 255, 0.1) 100%),linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 99, 255, 0.1) 0%, rgba(70, 233, 255, 0.1) 100%) "
```

The successful effect should looks like this:

[image: It's a triangle, with 180deg rotation]

Comment: in the second attempt remove the `()`

Comment: The second example works, but the problem is that one completely covers the other. Can you add an image to your question that shows how you want to have it?

Comment: Hi Jay, I have uploaded the picture. Thanks